# Arcology (Paolo Soleri)

Tags: etymology

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcology

Says Paolo coined the word.  But the concept was in use in SF as early as 1899.

I'd like to know when this word was coined, so that I could check my old SF to see if I can find it prior to that date.

Comment: The Wikipedia reference gives a reference for the work involved: published in 1973.

Comment: I recall reading the term sometime in the late 60s - early 70s.  You don't see it used very much, though, except perhaps is artsy architecture circles.

Comment: Can you provide reference to the 1899 usage you are referring to?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arcology gives a list of novels from 1899 through 2015 and a list of movies, TV shows video and board games incorporating the concept of arcology.  First novel was HG Wells, 1899;  Merriam Webster and Oxford Dictionaries say first known use 1969.

Answer (score 2):

[Arcology](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/arcology):

> - a concept in which the ideal city is a massive vertical structure, which preserves more of the natural environment, a concept combining architecture and ecology as envisioned by Paolo Soleri  (1919 –  2013).

Word Origin

> - arc(hitecture) + (ec)ology

(Dictionary.reference.com)

According to [Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=arcology&year_start=1900&year_end=2000&corpus=15&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2Carcology%3B%2Cc0): the term "arcology" has  been   used from the early  60's. It appears it  was used before Solery made it common in architecture.  The earlest usage instance I could find is from 1910:

[The Athenaeum](https://books.google.it/books?id=K6tAAQAAMAAJ&q=%22arcology%22&dq=%22arcology%22&hl=it&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQhoX987zKAhUEMhoKHZ6sClcQ6AEILDAC):(1910)

> - ...  it is, as the authors state, “practically a new one.” Much new matter has been added, and the chapters have been largely rearranged and rewritten. Although it is time that ***“the arcology of plants is a subject still in its infancy,”*** several ...

[image]

Paolo Soleri - Arcosanti : The City in the Image of Man